# Parse un-named paired PHP ini file

Tags: php

I have a .ini file with the following contents

```
SIGNALBOX/LOCATION
STATION
STATION CONCOURSE
STATION PLATFORM
STATION STEPS/STAIRS
TRACK
TUNNEL
WORKSHOP
```

And I'm trying to parse this with `parse_ini_file` function, however it's unable to parse it.

I want to avoid `locations[] =` before each value in the ini file, is there any way around this, to just create an array containing all of the values in the ini file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP-function file() will read the file to an array where each line is an element.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

For example:

```
<?php
    $locations = file('locations.ini');
    print_r($locations);
?>
```

Additionally, to get rid of the newline-characters after each element and to ignore empty lines in the file, you may add flags (use the bitwise OR-operator to add multiple) to the function, like so:

```
<?php
    $locations = file('locations.ini', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    print_r($locations);
?>
```

Comment: The OP might be interested in the parameter flags as well, particularly `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try file_get_contents() function :

```
<?php
    $ini_array = file_get_contents("yourinifile.ini");
    $location_array = explode("\n", $ini_array );
    print_r($location_array);    
?>
```